# Create file with Carriage Return character in filename

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

In my program's crash reports I have found that some users have files with CR character in filename (or %0D) that causes crash. How can I make that file on Windows or Mac so I can reproduce the crash?

Comment: On Windows you can hold ALT and type the ascii code (13) with a numpad.  Not sure about OSX or if this would work while renaming a file.

Comment: @GuntherFox if I do that in Save dialog or CMD I get a musical note symbol

Comment: Odd, that's the ascii value for it: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: I'd suggest your problem may be that the users' filenames are unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OSX:

```
#!/bin/sh
CR=$(echo X |tr X '\r')
ls >"foo${CR}bar"
```

makes a file that `ls` would show as `foo?bar`, where the `?` is an ASCII carriage return.